# github search code in repo gives empty result

Tags: github

I have a strange issue in my repo, when I search for i.e. "DEM"

**Steps:**

Open https://github.com/limex/schotterosm-cartocss-style/search?q=DEM

**Expected Result:**

4 Search Results. i.e. for the readme.md, as you can clearly see on the page https://github.com/limex/schotterosm-cartocss-style

**Observed Result:**

0 Results

I don't get any results for code searches within my repo.

**Funfact**:

My repo is a fork and the same search works on the original repo:
https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/search?q=DEM

Any idea why?

BR Günther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you repository is still being indexed. I also get that notification with the new search experience:

[image]

Comment: Looks like something happened when pushing the code. I will drop the repo and fork again. Thanks @rob-bos for checking